# CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition giving me wrong index in core text

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I have a question about `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition` in core text.

I have a text like this one:

```
Question: Hello, how are you today?
Answer: I am fine thank you
Question: great day isn't it?
...
```

On the above text i have set attributes for each one 'Question:' word to make it tappable . I am putting all this text on an `UITableview` cell. I have many similar cells with questions and answers.
When i touch The 'Question:' word on one of the cells the index i get is correct. I scroll down in the `UITableview` and then i have another text like the one before. When i tap on 'Question:' the index is not right.

This is how i implement the index.

```
index = CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line,CGPointMake(lineOrigins[i].x + pnt.x, pnt.y));
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "not right?" Have you taken into account that Core Text coordinates are upside-down from UIKit? Where is `pnt` coming from? Are you certain that it's aligned with the baseline lower-left corner of the text? There is very little to go on here.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. It is really strange. I am trying to fix it but i can not. Something is wrong with alignment. Actually when i get false index the text looks like this: suppose this text is in a new line "Question: Hello, how are you today?" then i break into the next line. When i tap at the right side of the words "Question: Hello, how are you today?" i get an index value but i shouldn't because there is no text after these words because i have a \n .

Comment: Then your CTLine likely has too many characters in it. Are you using the CTLine to actually perform the layout?

Comment: I am doing this CTFrameGetLineOrigins( ctFrame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), lineOrigins);CTLineRef line = (CTLineRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, i);
    
           index = CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line,CGPointMake(lineOrigins[i].x + pnt.x, pnt.y));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained where `pnt` comes from, but it is likely incorrect. `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition` takes a position relative to each line's origin in the text space (which is generally upside down of what you probably expect). See [Using CoreText and touches to create a clickable action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802697/using-coretext-and-touches-to-create-a-clickable-action) for an example of how to approach this.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I found what is wrong! I have different kind of fonts on the same line. The tappable area is in bold TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT this is why it breaks the line! It does not fit. I have set the attributes on the attribute string. So how do i find the correct line size with TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT and TimesNewRomanPSMT? Any help?

Comment: If you used that CTFrame to layout the attributed string, then it already took the fonts into account and `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` should work.