# How do you make a UITextView detect link part in the text and still have userInteractionDisabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uitextview

I have a textView that is layered on a tableView cell. I need the user to click on the tableView row to open a viewController but if the textView has a link it must be clickable and that's it, no copy, select etc.

If I allow user interaction like this:

```
textView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
textView.dataDetectorTypes =UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

the **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** is not called and I understand why but how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

What I'm looking for is the ability to specifically identify link and allow user to click on the link to open a browser and disable interaction for the rest of the textView. Also the entire row should be clickable as said above.

Attached is the image of my tableView cell row which shows the link is detected and interaction is also possible but this disables the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` inside the textView region.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this delegate - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange. I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: No, but i think that should deal with the text contained in the textView. What I'm looking for is the ability to specifically identify link and allow user to interact for that part and not for the whole textView.

Comment: If you have only one link always, then you can just do your functionality in didSelectRowAtIndexPath itself by checking whether the selected row contains link. But if you have multiple links, then you may try with uitapgesturerecognizer on textview (I guess.not sure)

Comment: This may help- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997708/uitextview-inside-uitableview

Comment: And what are you using for textview?? custom class?

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to add a UITextView with links to a cell, and want *didSelectRow* to be called when the user taps on anything but the link, then you should use **hitTest:withEvent:**

*Swift 3*

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // location of the tap
    var location = point
    location.x -= self.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= self.textContainerInset.top

    // find the character that's been tapped
    let characterIndex = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    if characterIndex < self.textStorage.length {
        // if the character is a link, handle the tap as UITextView normally would
        if (self.textStorage.attribute(NSLinkAttributeName, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) != nil) {
            return self
        }
    }

    // otherwise return nil so the tap goes on to the next receiver
    return nil
}
```

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/swifty-approach-to-handling-uitextviews-with-links-in-cells-d89e0e4b83d1#.1t6d8dua5) about this with a bit more details.

Comment: UITextView 0x7f9beb166400 is switching to TextKit 1 compatibility mode because its layoutManager was accessed. Getting this in iOS 16, Please guide what to be done.

Answer (score 3):

One possible (and complex) solution would be using `UIView`s with `UITapGestureRecogniser` inside your `UITextView`.

- Firstly, you will need to find the `NSRange` of your link.
- Convert `NSRange` to `UITextRange`
- Use code similar to the following to add a `UITapGestureRecogniser` right on top of the link-text in your `UITextView`.

  ```
  UITextPosition *pos = textView.endOfDocument;// textView ~ UITextView

  for (int i = 0; i < words*2 - 1; i++){// *2 since UITextGranularityWord considers a whitespace to be a word

      UITextPosition *pos2 = [textView.tokenizer positionFromPosition:pos toBoundary:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft];
      UITextRange *range = [textView textRangeFromPosition:pos toPosition:pos2];
      CGRect resultFrame = [textView firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range ];

      UIView* tapViewOnText = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:resultFrame];
      [tapViewOnText addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(targetRoutine)]];
      tapViewOnText.tag = 125;
      [textView addSubview:tapViewOnText];
      [tapViewOnText release];

      pos = pos2;
  ```

  }

What I have done in this code is, got the `UITextRange` of relevant text, get it's `firstRectForRange` and added a transparent tap-able `UIView` right on top of it.

You would have to get the range of your link using some `regEx`, convert it to `UITextRange`, and add tap-able `UIViews` over them. In case, there might be more than one link in a single `textView` you might add a `tag` to each view corresponding to their 'link', and open that link in the target method by checking it's tag.

NOTE: If your `UITextView`s are universally un-editable, you might want to try [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) instead. That is what I do in my `UITableViewCells`

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a bit complex and I'm hoping to get any easier solution before i dive into this at last

Comment: Have you given `TTTAttributedLabel` a look ?
It's pretty nifty. Let's you even call your own methods by adding 'links' to your text.

Comment: In the meantime, i'll try to think of something simpler, and less-taxing.

Comment: if tap able view can be added then why not uibutton?

Comment: You get the frame by this method. Once you have that, you can add any UI element as you like. `UIView`s are preferred since they are economical memory wise, compared to `UIButton`s. Ultimately, the choice is yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be ok for your purposes:

```
textView.editable=NO;
textView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
textView.dataDetectorTypes =UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

But in fact UITextView uses UIWebView parts internally, and this way may be slowly in table cells. 
[image]

I can advice to use `CoreText` or `NSAttributedString`'s with touches. For example you may read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802697/using-coretext-and-touches-to-create-a-clickable-action).

Comment: Setting selectable to NO won't detect any link, for iOS7 it is required YES.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5, iOS14**
Adjusting @Saoud Rizwan Answer because `hitTest` did not work well for me (it always called the same position multiple times). However here's my solution using `UITapGestureRecognizer`, where a tap on a link inside a `UITextView` will be detected.

First configure your Tap event to the `UITextView`

```
contentTextView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textViewTapped(_:))))
```

The `CellTapped` implementation:

```
@objc func cellTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var location = sender.location(in: contentTextView)
    location.x -= contentTextView.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= contentTextView.textContainerInset.top

    let characterIndex = contentTextView.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: contentTextView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    if characterIndex < contentTextView.textStorage.length {
        if let url = contentTextView.textStorage.attribute(.link, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? URL {
            // The user tapped on a link!
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // here: The user tapped somewhere in the textView but not on a link!
}
```

Comment: contentTextView.layoutManager.characterIndex(...) this function is main in this use case but in iOS 16 UITextView is using TextKit 2 and use of layoutManager is cautioned. How to work with TextKit 2