# Manage URL and handle user tap in a text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

in my client app i have a problem and i don't know how to resolve it, I've tried various solutions, but none of them worked for me. I'm going to explain my problem.

My app makes a request to a web server that responds with a JSON where there is a text that contains links. This is a simply example of text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{[Expansiel GIE-
>http://thisis.mylink.com/spip.php?action111]}} consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut {{Directeur général }} : [John Lucas-
>http://thisis.mylink.com/spip.php?action546] labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in m 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
Directeur Technique & du Patrimoine : [Simon Lucas-
>http://thisis.mylink/spip.php?action786] occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Now what my client wants is to do something similar like a web page so i should delte the link from the text but associate it to the near word and make it "clicable" (like an HTML href). An example of this is to intercpet the link of

```
 http://thisis.mylink.com/spip.php?action111
```

when the user tap on the word **Expansiel GIE** and the same for the other links. The tap doesn't need to open a web page but execute a custom action.

Few weeks ago i asked for the same question [How to detect all links in a text and handle tap on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913728/how-to-detect-all-links-in-a-text-and-handle-tap-on-them)

i was be able to dected all link in the text and intercept their click but that solution is not what i need. So now anyone can help me to find the correct solution for my projects? For other informations or clarifications just ask.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Still dont understand what you need, you want to ask how to create tappable text (add url to the `GIE` text) or handle the tap to do custom action but not open webpage?

Comment: I'd like to know how to create tappable text (add url to the GIE text). Handling the tap should not be a problem.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-to-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a) should be what you are looking for, your question title is totally misleading to what you want to ask

Comment: Is it an option to modify the text so that it's more like html? I mean with links marked with <a href> tags. If so then UITextView is able to handle it automatically.